# How to create a regular expression based on position and a delimiter

Tags: c#, regex

I want to create a regex to extract string based on my position and then traverse to the right and left till I encounter a specified delimiter.

For eg. AWESOME DUDE is the string and I know a position say 3(starting from )) (between E and S). I would like to go to the both sides till I reach an empty space.

Basically I want to create a function in C# where I pass the position and a string and a delimiter and get the complete string. So in the above example I would be passing 'AWESOME DUDE' as the string, position as 3 and delimiter as ' '(space) and my result should be 'AWESOME'

**PS - Do not want to use a split. Want a regex preferably and not a string manipulation.**

Is it feasible ?

Comment: It's quite unclear what you ask. In general a regex is oblivious to its position at that moment (that's one of the properties of a regex). For some cases, it can be done.

Comment: Would you please be able to share those scenarios in which it can be done? I am thinking if there is any way other than direct string manipulation

Comment: Why do you pass the position 3?

Comment: That's the point. It heavily depends on the specifications. For some regexes it can be done, if only two types of characters are allowed, etc. No "generic scenarios"

Comment: @AvinashRaj : Because I actually have a big line. Just wondering if it can be done..

Comment: @CommuSoft : UNderstand.. So no generic way... THat is what I was looking for. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

The following regex works for grep/perl, I assume it should work for your scenario too. Your starting position does not matter here (this means if you pass a string with more than 2 words, you'll get more than 1 output, unfortunately), it goes to both sides until it reaches a space (assuming that space is not further than 1000 characters away, else you'll need to adjust that).

```
'[\s][A-Z,a-z,0-9]{0,1000}[\s]'
```